# Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{e^{2x}+1}$

Tags: integration, proof-verification

> Evaluate $$\int \frac{dx}{e^{2x}+1}$$

Here's what I did:

$$t=e^{2x} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{t(t+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int \frac{dt}{t} - \int \frac{dt}{t+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln \left|t\right| - \ln|t+1|\right) +C = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left|\frac{t}{t+1}\right|+ C = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left|\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}\right| + C$$

I've understood the evaluation is wrong. Where's my mistake?

Comment: $De^{2x} = 2e^{2x}$.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} (e^{2x})=2e^{2x}$. So $dt=2e^{2x}dx$ . $dx=\frac{dt}{2t}$You missed the $2$.

Comment: Right. I've fixed that. Nevertheless, the evaluation is still wrong.

Comment: It should have been according to my notes: $-\frac{1}{2} \ln (e^{-2x} + 1) + C$.

Comment: And according wolframalpha: $x - \frac{1}{2}\ln(e^{2x} + 1)+ C$.

Comment: That's the same function, since $\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1} = \frac{1}{e^{-2x}+1}$.

Comment: This is the same thing to your answer, so you are correct

Comment: @hibye Wolfram's answer is the answer you got, since $x=\frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x})$.

Comment: Also, you don't need absolute value symbols here, since $e^{2x}$ and $e^{2x}+1$ are always positive for real $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:$$\frac{1}{2}\left( \log(e^{2x})-\log(e^{2x}+1)\right)=x-\frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x}+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac1{e^{2x}+1}dx=\int\frac{e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}dx=-\frac12\int\frac{de^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}=-\frac12\int\frac{d(1+e^{-2x})}{1+e^{-2x}}
=\frac12\ln(1+e^{-2x})+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Dividing both numerator and denominator by $e^{2x}$, $$\frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+ 1}\right|$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{1}{1+ e^{-2x}}\right|$$

$$= -\frac{1}{2}\log\left|e^{-2x}+ 1\right|$$.

Of course, it is also equal to Dr. Graubner's result.